# Apply a condition to only the unique values in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where there are a bunch of unique values in one column, however I need find the location where a certain condition is met for ONLY the unique values and not over the entire dataframe.

```
COL1 | VAR1 | VAR2
A    | 0    | 1
A    | 1    | 2
B    | 0    | 1
B    | 1.5  | 2.5
C    | 0    | 2
C    | 2    | 3 
C    | 3    | 4 
D    | 0    | 1
D    | 2.5  | 4
```

My desired outcome would be to find all the locations in the dataframe where VAR2 is not equal to the next rows VAR1 for only the unique values in COL1. For example the following output

```
COL1 | VAR1  | VAR2
B    | 0     | 1 
D    | 0     | 1
```

I have applied the following codes to get my condition to work. But I haven't a clue how to do it for only the unique values

```
[df['VAR1'] != df['VAR2'].shift(-1)]
```

This for obvious reasons has given me all the locations where the next value in COL1 is unique.

Your help will be very appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to go through my question :)

Comment: But B and D in COL1 are not unique

Comment: B and D are unique from each other in COL1

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)?

```py
mask = (df['VAR1'] != df['VAR2'].shift(-1)) & (~df['VAR1'].duplicated())
df[mask]
```

Comment: I think this works. Does this condition --> (~df['COL1'].duplicated()), ensure that the first condition is applied to only where COL1 is not duplicated? :)

Comment: @MichaelRay Exact `df['COL1'].duplicated()` is false for all entries when first seen and true elsewhere, `~` is the boolean negation operator. so `~df['COL1'].duplicated()` is true for non-duplicated values only.